# SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow pause until action not working well if any of the two field is empty

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-designer-workflow, pause

I am using SharePoint Designer 2013.

I have a workflow which sends email notifications on the following times:

After creation of the List item I used pause until Start Date / Time.
1: On the task start date / time it sends an email.
Then pause until End Date / Time.

2: On the task end date and time it sends an email.
Then when I do pause for 5 minutes and then send an email

It is working when the both items Start Date /Time and End Date / Time is filled in but it doesn't send any email if any of these two value is empty or not filled in.

I am attaching Screenshots as well. If someone know how can I fix this if any of the above two fields are empty, it would still send an email. This will be great.

My biggest challenge is that SharePoint Designer does not provide an "Is Empty" conditional option for Date fields, like it does for other fields.  How can I conditionally Pause my workflow only when the Date field is non-empty?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: How would the new logic work?  If the workflow determines is Pause times on those two columns, then if those values are missing, what you prefer the behavior be?

Comment: Hi Willman, the new logic will work like I have two columns, start date / time and End date / time. How it is working at the moment is if the start date/ time is empty, it will not the perform any action which is defined at the end date / time. As both values are using pause until loop. That's the issue I want to resolve at the moment.

I want the it to perform the actions on the end date / time even if the start date / time field is left empty. 

Which at the moment is not working.

I hope this makes sense. If you need further clarification then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you just need to put you `Pause` action in the condition, but everything else outside it.  Since "empty" date fields end up looking in SharePoint Designer workflows like 
'1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM' you have to perform a 'less than' comparison to see if that date is valid.

It would look something like this:

```
If Start date is greater than 1/1/1990 then
        Pause until start date
Send Email
```

So that the `Send` is **not** inside the `If` block, it is after.  The only action inside the `If` block is the `Pause`.

Comment: Hi Willman, Yes you are right, but the problem is I have both the values start date / time and end date / time which are the date / time columns. So the options it comes up with are:
If Start Date / time is (equals, not equals, is greater than, greater than or equal to, is less than, is less than or equal to, equals(ignoring time) so the If start date / time gives me these values to select from, empty is not there unfortunately as it is date / time column.

Comment: You are right, I had forgotten that SPD workflows treat empty Dates as '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM', I updated my answer with the workaround for testing whether the field is "empty".

Comment: OK Willman. So this means that if I want to do this:

 If date is greater than 1/1/1990
Send Email

This will send an email if the field is not empty, theoretically?

Comment: yes, sorry, I put the condition backwards, you only want to `Pause` when the date field value is `greater than`.

Comment: That's great thank you. I have a question that if we imagine we did :
If date is greater than 1/1/1990 then
    Pause until start date
Send Email

As the Send Email is not in the same block. If the value is less than or empty then anyway it's gonna send email. If I am right? But we want to send the email only if the IF statement is correct.

and then move on to next statement. For example Change End date / time. Now it is clear that it will not stop just there due to the empty date but it is just an extra clearance question in my mind.

Comment: Yes, the `If` block does **not** stop the workflow executing, regardless of whether you have an optional `else` block, it will always continue on the execute actions that are outside and after the conditional block.

Comment: Ok that's great and makes proper sense now and if the If statement is correct and then pause until and then if in the same block I enter Send Email. Then it's only gonna send the email if the statement is correct else it will move to the next block ignoring whatever is inside the If block. yay

Comment: yes, you got it.

Comment: Excellent man. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can add If conditin above the pause action.

If the start date is empty, send email or other actions, else, pause until start date.

Comment: Hi, I think you have missed my whole point.
 I have two columns, start date / time and End date / time. How it is working at the moment is if the start date/ time is empty, it will not the perform any action which is defined at the end date / time. As both values are using pause until loop. That's the issue I want to resolve at the moment. I want the it to perform the actions on the end date / time even if the start date / time field is left empty. Which at the moment is not working. I hope this makes sense. If you need further clarification then please let me know.